# How find duplicates in Python Pandas DataFrame across parent groups for all children?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

Given the below DataFrame, how do I find the duplicates across parent groupings for all parents?

```
data = {'buildings': {0: 'mansion', 1: 'mansion', 2: 'house', 3: 'house', 4: 'house', 5: 'apartment', 6: 'apartment', 7: 'apartment', 8: 'apartment', 9: 'apartment', 10: 'apartment', 11: 'apartment', 12: 'condo', 13: 'condo', 14: 'condo', 15: 'condo', 16: 'condo', 17: 'condo'},
'vehicles': {0: 'plane', 1: 'boat', 2: 'small car', 3: 'small car', 4: 'big car', 5: 'small truck', 6: 'big truck', 7: 'big truck', 8: 'big truck', 9: 'big truck', 10: 'big truck', 11: 'big truck', 12: 'condo', 13: 'condo', 14: 'condo', 15: 'condo', 16: 'condo', 17: 'condo'},
'animals': {0: 'plane', 1: 'boat', 2: 'ape', 3: 'fish', 4: 'big car', 5: 'small truck', 6: 'chimp', 7: 'monkey', 8: 'lemur', 9: 'tiger', 10: 'lion', 11: 'jaguar', 12: 'bobcat', 13: 'monkey', 14: 'lemur', 15: 'tiger', 16: 'lion', 17: 'jaguar'},
'Value': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17}}

g = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(by=['buildings', 'vehicles', 'animals']).sum()
print(g)
```

Output:

```
                                   Value
buildings vehicles    animals           
apartment big truck   chimp            6
                      jaguar          11
                      lemur            8
                      lion            10
                      monkey           7
                      tiger            9
          small truck small truck      5
condo     condo       bobcat          12
                      jaguar          17
                      lemur           14
                      lion            16
                      monkey          13
                      tiger           15
house     big car     big car          4
          small car   ape              2
                      fish             3
mansion   boat        boat             1
          plane       plane            0
```

Forgive the nonsensical data, but the children are vehicles and animals. buildings column is not a child because it is in the 0th column position.

I want to identify the duplicates within the child columns. Here, there are 5 duplicates in the animals child column:
monkey, lemur, tiger, lion, jaguar.

There are 0 duplicates in the vehicles child column.

I'm looking for a dataframe consisting of only the rows containing the 5 duplicates. Since there are 5 duplicates here all of which having 2 values each, the output dataframe should be 10 rows long.

Lastly, the width of the dataframes may vary. (Here there were 2 children columns, but in another case there may be up to 10 children columns).

My apologies if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

In your case try with `duplicated`

```
out = g[g.index.get_level_values(2).duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[294]: 
                             Value
buildings vehicles  animals       
apartment big truck jaguar      11
                    lemur        8
                    lion        10
                    monkey       7
                    tiger        9
condo     condo     jaguar      17
                    lemur       14
                    lion        16
                    monkey      13
                    tiger       15
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in this instance but if I wanted to try to find the duplicates of level 1, how would I do that? Changing the 2 to 1 in this example yields unexpected results. I would expect an empty DataFrame since there are no duplicates across the building parents. (i.e. big truck is only under apartment, small truck is only under apartment, etc.)